# Drupal 7 - unable to load template file

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I moved the 'mysite_theme' theme folder from ‘/sites/default/themes’ to ‘/sites/all/themes’.

The css, themes everything is working fine. But, I have some php code for a page /sites/all/themes/mysite_themes/templates/node--80.tpl.php. This is not working anymore.

I cleared the cache from the performance page. But still it is not working.

Am I missing anything? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is 80 the id of the node you are trying to theme?

Comment: You should enter to "Edit" required node and check it's ID. If ID is not 80 - rename your template file

Comment: @ArditMeti  you are right. Thanks a ton. The id was wrong.

Comment: @DrHolera you are right. Thanks a ton. The id was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your id is most likely wrong. Make sure the node id in your template filename is correct.

Please mark check if this ticket is done.